# MVVM Light SimpleIoc

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

I'm using WPF with MVVM Light in my project. I have some small question about `SimpleIoC` containter and DI. Which is the better way to use it or tell me if I don't need to use DI there.

There is my VM constructor:

```
public MainViewModel(IDialogService dialogService, IChannelObserverService channelObserverService, IInternalBroadcastService internalBroadcastService, 
                         IUserDataAccessService userDataAccessService, IUserService userService)
```

And SimpleIoC register:

```
 SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>(() => {
            return new MainViewModel(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IDialogService>(),
                                     SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IChannelObserverService>(),
                                     SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IInternalBroadcastService>(),
                                     SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IUserDataAccessService>(),
                                     SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IUserService>()); });
```

Please tell me, do I need to use DI there?
First I had using all services like this:

```
public MainViewModel(){...}

User user = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IUserService>().GetCurrentLoggedUser();
```

or this:

```
private IDialogService dialogService;

public MainViewModel()
{
    dialogService = = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IUserService>();
}

private void MyMethod()
{
    dialogService.ShowQuestionDialog(abc,abc,abc);
}
```

So I didn't use DI when I was creating my View-Models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use the `DI` as it enables the development of loosely coupled code. Through `DI`, you can **decrease tight coupling** between software components. Also, it makes **unit testing** convenient.

I would suggest to have constructor like this (as you have mentioned in your post)

```
public MainViewModel(IDialogService dialogService, IChannelObserverService channelObserverService, IInternalBroadcastService internalBroadcastService, 
                         IUserDataAccessService userDataAccessService, IUserService userService)
```

But registration can be simplified as

```
 SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
 //// Other service registrations.

 SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>(); // without injecting the other dependent types.
```

With this DI will take to inject the right dependencies while creating an instance of `MainViewModel`.

So with this above approach, you don't need to Resolve the instance inside your code as it is already inject in constructor, so service code can be simplified as

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    dialogService.ShowQuestionDialog(abc,abc,abc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice :) I didn't know hat I don't need to create full constructor in registration.